Restricting users to submit only one expense per day
I'm looking for some guidance. I have created an Expense Tracking App, where my custom object is called Expense__c. It has the Submission_Date_c field, which is a Date/time field, and the Status_c  picklist field.
I wrote this logic to avoid users sending more than one Expense per day (Just one Expense sent by user per day), I'm new working on Dev Console so need your help.
public class ExpenseBeforeTriggerHandler {
public void onBeforeInsert(List<Expense__c> newList){
    List<Expense__c> existingRecordsToday = [
    SELECT Id FROM Expense_c 
        WHERE Submission_Date_c = TODAY LIMIT 1 
    ];
    if (!existingRecordsToday.isEmpty()) {
        for (Expense__c obj : newList) {
            obj.addError('Only one Expense can be created per day'); 
        }
    }
}
    }


Fellow 'stackers - I agree this post is a close candidate but let's give the author time to update with more contextual code.  Dates in general is a facinating minefield of code cockups.

... is called Expense__c  ->  The code syntax suggests that Expense__c is a Type (class) not a variable named Expense__c

... avoid users sending more than one Expense per day  -> So several expenses with the same date is OK but just cannot submit them all at once on the same day?

.. avoid users sending more than one Expense per day -> so given mutiple expenses, regardless of expense dates, only one at a time - one per day - can be submitted?

@radarbob - closing a question is the best way to allow the author to update the question without it getting an answer, which would "lock in" the code.  We're pretty good at reopening questions when they have been improved to meet Code Review standards.

There is not enough code here. I cannot make any assumptions about the method arguments and no assumption of what TODAY is. ==> which is the mindset a programer should always take.
However onBeforeInsert() assumes "submitted" dates in all objects is exactly the same date. A date that is not determined before the objects are injected to the method.
It appears that if any expense has TODAY date (SELECT WHERE) then all expenses do (for obj:newList)
Make explicit date comparisons. Or something like existingRecordsToday.contains(thisDate)
The best comparison is actually by ID because that's what SELECT-WHERE returns. In any case, a guard ! isEmpty check is unnecessary because a salesforce forEach equivalent should handle an empty list just fine.
Testing only for isEmpty assumes earlier Date comparisons was correct. Mr. Spock would say "I am not sanguine, captain"

This code is fully dependent on the system date when the program is running.

There is no telling what dates are in existingRecordsToday and newList objects

The time zones of executing computer and original data generating program

Program run time crossing local midnight

Any intervening processing (both computer and manual) or delay in processing causing date "un-synch".

Date object resolution. Many languages` dates are a combined date & time, with millisecond precision. Two objects with the same date but with time components miliseconds different will compare as not-equal.


